# printer driver host for 32bit application has stopped working

Tags: c#, printing

I have an application written in C# that prints out labels from various user controls and forms. I am encountering an error where every so often I get a little windows dialog saying "printer driver host for 32bit application has stopped working".

Since its not happening directly after printing I am not sure if its anything to do with my code, but here is the function I use to print out the labels;

```
            try
            {
                fontware_code128 Barcode = new fontware_code128();
                Font myFont = new Font("Arial", 24);

                PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
                printDoc.DocumentName = "Standard Label";
                printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = Helper.GetPrinterName();
                printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
                printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new Margins(10, 10, 10, 10);
                printDoc.PrintController = new StandardPrintController(); 

                printDoc.PrintPage += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    args.Graphics...
                };

                printDoc.Print();

                this.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, any more detail needed just ask!

Comment: The printer driver crashed.  Very little you can do about that.  Visit the manufacturer's web site to look for a driver update.  Or get another one and spend more money on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This article](http://www.techerator.com/2010/10/fix-print-driver-host-for-32bit-applications-has-stopped-working-error-in-windows-7/) says that the error can happen because Microsoft did not include all the print drivers on the OEM installation CD so the printer might get installed incorrectly. The fix as outlined by the article is:

1. Uninstall any printers you already have installed on your computer
2. Re-install printer as locally attached network printer
3. Type in printer's hostname or IP address. Make sure to uncheck *Query the printer and automatically select the driver*.
4. Click Windows Update to get updated list of printer drivers and find the appropriate driver.

Reference: http://www.techerator.com/2010/10/fix-print-driver-host-for-32bit-applications-has-stopped-working-error-in-windows-7/

Comment: Thank you for the article link, I have followed the steps - hope it works!